# match one column to another column of another file unix

Tags: unix, join, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have file_1

```
BlockID
VT11742
VT11744
VT11050
VT11870
VT12147
VT12149
VT12176
VT12180
```

and file_2

```
AB Ref2        VICTOR 
crc_31-C1        VT11929
crc_31-C2     VT11929 C2
crc_31-N VT11929 NORMAL
crc_32-C1        VT11050
crc_32-C2     VT11050 C2
crc_33-C1        VT11656
crc_33-C2     VT11656 C2
crc_33-N VT11656 NORMAL
crc_34-C1        VT11981
crc_34-C2     VT11981 C2
```

My desired output is to print out the first column of file2 when the ever the first column of file1 matches file2 and print out in the same order of file2 and print when there is "no match"

output

```
BlockID
VT11742 no_match
VT11744 no_match
VT11050 crc_32-C1
VT11870 no_match
VT12147 no_match
VT12149 no_match
VT12176 no_match
VT12180 no_match
```

I thought I could do something like this
grep -Ff file1 file2 > output

Comment: You say you want to `print out in the same order of file2` but that's not what you show in your expected output. Please fix your question to be consistent/accurate. Also include `VT11929` in `file1` so we can see the expected output when there's multiple matches in `file2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following(written and tested with your shown samples).

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} FNR>1{$0=$0 OFS ($1 in a?a[$1]:"no_match")} 1'  file_2  file_1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
BlockID
VT11742 no_match
VT11744 no_match
VT11050 crc_32-C2
VT11870 no_match
VT12147 no_match
VT12149 no_match
VT12176 no_match
VT12180 no_match
```

Answer (score 0):

To `print out in the same order of file2` as you **say** (but don't show in your example) you want:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (NR==1) print; else a[$1]; next} FNR>1{print $2, ($2 in a ? $1 : "no_match")}' file1 file2
BlockID
VT11929 no_match
VT11929 no_match
VT11929 no_match
VT11050 crc_32-C1
VT11050 crc_32-C2
VT11656 no_match
VT11656 no_match
VT11656 no_match
VT11981 no_match
VT11981 no_match
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk` script. For unclear request. Hope it works for you.

`script.awk`

```
FNR == NR { # process file 1 only
    keysArr[$2] = $1; # read each 2nd field into array
    next;   # skip any further handling
}
FNR > 1{    # process file 2 form line 2
    $2 = "no match";   # set default match result
    if ($1 in keysArr) { # match key in file 1
         $2 = keysArr[$1]; # overwrite 2nd output field
    }
}
1           # ouput everything computed for file 2
```

`input.1.txt`

```
BlockID
VT11742
VT11744
VT11050
VT11870
VT12147
VT12149
VT12176
VT12180
```

`input.2.txt`

```
AB Ref2        VICTOR
crc_31-C1        VT11929
crc_31-C2     VT11929 C2
crc_31-N VT11929 NORMAL
crc_32-C1        VT11050
crc_32-C2     VT11050 C2
crc_33-C1        VT11656
crc_33-C2     VT11656 C2
crc_33-N VT11656 NORMAL
crc_34-C1        VT11981
crc_34-C2     VT11981 C2
```

running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.2.txt input.1.txt
```

output:

```
BlockID
VT11742 no match
VT11744 no match
VT11050 crc_32-C2
VT11870 no match
VT12147 no match
VT12149 no match
VT12176 no match
VT12180 no match
```